# How to copy elements in a list different number of times?

Tags: f#

If I have a list consisting of elements `[5;10;15]`, how can I get an output array in which the number of times element x from the input list is repeated `x/5` times, or using any other integral expression to specify the number of repetitions?

So like for this list, the expected output should be `[5; 10; 10; 15; 15; 15]`

Comment: `[5;10;15]` is a list, do you want to create a list or an array?

Comment: I do not really care, any would do :) I will fix the terminology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, transform every element of the input list into a list with that many elements. To transform every element of a list, use `List.map`. To create a list with a given number of elements, use `List.replicate`:

```
let f lst = 
    lst 
    |> List.map (fun x -> List.replicate (x/5) x)
```

Let's test that:

```
> f [5; 10]
[ [5]; [10; 10] ]
```

And then, all that's left to do is concatenate all those lists into a big list using `List.concat`:

```
let f lst = 
    lst 
    |> List.map (fun x -> List.replicate (x/5) x)
    |> List.concat
```

Or you can fuse `map` and `concat` together in `collect`:

```
let f lst = 
    lst 
    |> List.collect (fun x -> List.replicate (x/5) x)
```

Comment: Oh gosh, thank you! But I am(like you are) getting a list of lists, how can it be changed such that the out of f [5;10] is [5, 10, 10] instead of [[5]; [10, 10]]?

Comment: Yes, that you can fuse map and concat

Comment: Oh, it is not just fusing the methods but the lists! Thanks :)))))))

Answer (score 0):

You can define the following function returning a sequence using a [sequence expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences#sequence-expressions) with nested `for` loops:

```ml
let repeatedSeq (s, itemCount) = 
    seq { for item in s do for i in 1..itemCount(item) -> item }
```

And then do:

```
let list = [5; 10; 15]
let repeatedList = repeatedSeq(list, fun i -> i/5) |> Seq.toList
```

Which results in `[5; 10; 10; 15; 15; 15]` as required.  This approach avoids materializing any intermediate sequences as lists or arrays.

If you want your final result to be an array do `|> Seq.toArray` instead.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/okDiPP).